# Equivalent of SQL Having clause

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to filter documents that have the same value in one or multiple fields.
So basically I need to run something like SQL `HAVING` clause.

I found that it's possible to filter aggregations, but I need to get documents that meets some conditions that are related to other documents in that list. So I need to query index by aggregation result, that are based on initial document.

Is there a way to do this in ElasticSearch?

For example - consider an index of documents with number. What is the way to query documents where this number repeats in whole index?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using PHP with Doctrine? It's great, works most of the time and you can use HAVING clause.